# Newsletter subscription box positioning in footer

Tags: blocks, xml, newsletter

**EDIT: SOLVED, see answer below (will accept when I can).**

I wanted to move the newsletter block on the frontend of my site to the footer.

So I changed this in newsletter.xml: (
Previously the reference was `<reference name="left">`)

```
    <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

This has worked in that the newsletter has moved to the footer, but how can I control where the block is positioned within the footer.

I tried this in my templates ... page/html/footer.phtml:

```
<div class="footer-container">
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="nine columns">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
            </div>
            <div class="three columns">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer.newsletter') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
...
```

But this duplicates the newsletter block. Now it appears once in the place I want it to be (in the three-column div) but then appears again in the nine-column div.

I assume this is because it is included in the '$this->getChildHtml()' call.

I would really appreciate any help, thanks. Definitely missing a trick somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the `getChildHtml()` call which as far as I understand was printing out ALL blocks in footer, so of course it was printing out the newsletter block in that call. And then my call `getChildHtml('footer.newsletter')` was printing the newsletter block again.

I changed `getChildHtml()` to `getChildHtml('cms_footer_links')` and now that is the only block showing there (which is what I wanted anyway).

Comment: But it's not the best way to do. You can delete all unnecessary blocks with layout xml. `<remove name="block_name">`

Comment: But if I `<remove name="footer.newsletter">` that means the footer will not show anywhere.

Comment: Why all footer? Only block which you mention.

Comment: Sorry I meant "that means the newsletter block will not show anywhere". If I remove the newsletter block using `<remove name="footer.newsletter">`, the newsletter will not show when I call `getChildHtml('footer.newsletter')` in the place where I want it to appear, as it does now.

Answer (score 4):

Just add below single line & it works

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `after` or `before` attribute:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" after="footer_links" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Hi, I had tried the before attribute before but no change.

I think the problem was that the newsletter was included as a child block of footer so was printing out there too (in the nine column div). I have changed the 'getChildHtml()' to be 'getChildHtml(cms_footer_links')' as that is the only block I want to be called in this area anyway.

Comment: Did you tried before="cms_footer_links"? And did you clear all cache?

Comment: I haven't tried this but I suspect it would mean the block would appear once above the footer links and then again where I have called it in the HTML. The issues was the call 'getChildHtml()' which was getting ALL child blocks, in addition to my call 'getChildHtml('footer.newsletter')' which was getting the newsletter block again, so of course they were showing twice. Anyway I have solved my problem, thanks for your help!